# Stargazer Title

Tags: r, stargazer

I have an issue with giving my stargazer tables in R the right title. I can change the title itself but it always says "Table 1:" before the title. Unfortunately I have more than one table so I'd like to change that to "Title 2", "Title 3" for the latter tables. How is that done? This is what my tables mostly look like:

```
   stargazer(fixed_coups, fixed_coups_navco, title="Fixed-Effect Linear Regression Results Coups", style="apsr",
          align=TRUE, column.labels = c("Without NAVCO", "With NAVCO"),
          covariate.labels = c("Lagged Repression", "Coup", "Attempt", "Log Population", "Log GDP per capita",
                               "Non-Violent Campaign", "Violent Campaign"),
          dep.var.labels = ("Repression"))
```

Comment: What is your output format. In LaTeX, you can use `\setcounter` (I think) to alter the value of the table counter. Other output formats would need something different.

Comment: Latex should handle table numbering, not stargazer. A typical approach is writing the stargazer output to a .tex file then `\include`ing each table in your main file.

Comment: Using In LaTeX. Thank you, I'll try using \setcounter.